# This TableLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless how to resolve from this warning

Tags: android, layout

I have tablelayout inside linearlayout but it shows me this warning message
 This TableLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless 
 how to overcome from this warning  can ane help me .
 Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >

          <TableLayout>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtPass"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Password"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:width="100dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edPass"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:password="true" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
              </TableRow>
          </TableLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need top most LinearLayout when you dont have anything inside LinearLayout except TableLayout? One of these layout should be enough. Remove either LinearLayout (or) TableLayout. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: now i have this layout <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        
        
        
        <TextView
           </TextView> and <EditText> inside it 
    
        
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

Comment: That should work. Are you still getting that warning message?

Comment: Actually i want one view like login page but i want it in centre on the activity so how can i achive this plz help me .

Comment: You are sure that you dont have LinearLayout in XML file right? If so, clean the project.  Close the file and open it again.

Comment: You may need to use RelativeLayout. Here is link with example. http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/

Comment: ok let me try this also and one more question dear actually i want this layout for sumsang galaxy tab and motorola xoom. then what should i do for that .

Comment: You don't need to worry! it should work on every device. Make sure hieght/wieght are set in DP not in Pixel. If you are ok with this answer, mark it as answer (ticket mark beside this disccusion). Further question related to RelativeLayout, post your updated code and post new question. Enjoy programming.

Comment: Hey im new to stackoverflow how to mark it as answer thats gud answers you r given to me. Thanks for that.

Comment: Right beside my answer (left to you) you will see tick mark with white background. You need to click it to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Through the warning, the system just wants to say you have the space to optimize your layout code.There is no need to care much about it if you do not want to optimize your code now.

Comment: Still, it's good practice to pay attention to warnings - they usually have a point! In this case both layouts are unnecessary, so one should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TableLayout tags and put the attributes into the TableRow tags.

Answer (score 0):

If are looking for layout as below then the xml is as follows

[image: Password_layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password" />
<EditText
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password" />


</LinearLayout>
```