# Why does the compiler say I'm not giving my TableLayout an id when I am?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-view, android-tablelayout

I've rearranged my code that dynamically creates widgets/views and, although the xml layout appears to be "well-formed" (it compiles), when I get to the corresponding "setContentView()" it crashes.

IOW:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ondemandandautomatic_dynamicauthorize); <-- crashes when I F6 (Eclipse) on this line
```

...So then I noticed in my xml layout file a warning icon: "This TableLayout is useless (no children, no background, no id)"

Well, I'm going to add the children at runtime; why does it need a background? And the big question: why does it say it has no id, when I've added one:

```
<TableLayout>
android:id="@id/tlDynamicRows" <-- IT'S RIGHT THERE!!!
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
</TableLayout>
```

There is another warning at the  that says, "This TableRow or its TableRow parent is useless"

Here's the entire xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlDynamic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow> <- This is where it says, "This TableRow or its TableRow parent is useless"

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/demand"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/time"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/space"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/contact"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TableLayout> <- This is where it says, "says, "This TableRow or its TableRow parent is useless"
        android:id="@id/tlDynamicRows"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What could be causing this revolting development?

Updated:

When looking over my post, I saw that the final "TableLayout" in the xml had a superfluous right angle bracket. So, I took the first one out, and now I get an err msg, namely, "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/tlDynamicRows')."

That part of the xml is now:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@id/tlDynamicRows"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableLayout>
```

What gives?

Update:

Here's the xml that finally works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlDynamic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/demand"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/time"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/space"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:text="@string/contact"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlDynamicRows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I still had a warning message to change this line in the TableLayout inside the ScrollView:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I did, and it seemed to make no difference - but it got rid of the Warning, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points to be noted in the XML you posted above:

1- When you are using the first Table Row

```
  <TableRow> <- This is where it says, "This TableRow or its TableRow parent is useless"
```

In this line you are not specifying the layout_height and layout_width attributes of the row, that is why you are getting "useless" in warning.

2- Another point is try giving id to Table Layout in Scroll view at the botton as:

```
 android:id="@+id/tlDynamicRows"
```

instead of

```
 android:id="@id/tlDynamicRows"
```

hope these work for you.

Comment: All the examples I see do have the "+"

Removing all of them gives me that error msg now in three elements, not just one, e.g. this:

android:id="@id/scrollViewHost"
        
gives this:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value 

'@id/scrollViewHost').

...and the same is true for @id/tlDynamic and @id/tlDynamicRows.

So I added back the "+" and, after including the layout_width and layout_height properties for the TableRow, it finally works. I've added my new xml above for posterity.

Comment: I'm still getting, "This TableRor layout or TableLayout parent is useless" but it's doing exactly what I want it to do...

Comment: @ClayShannon ..this link might help you understanding Table Layouts...have a look...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because you have just one TableRow, try adding more rows to see if this persists.

References:

- [Android - ListViews inside tableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229324/android-listviews-inside-tablelayout)
- [This TableLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless how to resolve from this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905731/this-tablelayout-layout-or-its-linearlayout-parent-is-useless-how-to-resolve-fro)
- [Android warning "This TableRow view is useless (no children, no background, no id)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848428/android-warning-this-tablerow-view-is-useless-no-children-no-background-no-i)
- [Eclipse complains about uselessness of elements in layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698978/eclipse-complains-about-uselessness-of-elements-in-layout-xml/8699161#8699161)